# ¿Cómo invocar la función de un thread y asignarle parámetros?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy aprendiendo threading en python y me surge un problema. Con este código consigo que dos tareas se ejecuten al mismo tiempo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
import threading

def dormir():
    print("Me duermo")
    time.sleep(10)

    print("Me despierto")
def soñar():
    for i in range(9):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i," Zzzzzzzz")

hilo1 = threading.Thread(target=dormir)
hilo2 = threading.Thread(target=soñar)
hilo1.start()
hilo2.start()
```

¿Por qué no funciona si programo las funciones con argumentos?, por ejemplo, una variable que defina el valor de `time.sleep()`.

Comment: agrega un parametro a la funcion y para llamar al thread con parametros es de la siguiente forma `threading.Thread(target=dormir, args=(20,)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si revisamos la firma de [`threading.Thread()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread)

> class threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(),
>   kwargs={}, *, daemon=None)

vemos que tenemos dos parámetro interesante `args` y `kwargs`, el primero nos servirá para pasar los parámetros de forma posicional y el segundo por nombre.

Por ejemplo:

```
def dormir(segundos):
    print("Me duermo")
    time.sleep(segundos)
    print("Me despierto")

hilo1 = threading.Thread(target=dormir,args=(15,))
```

o bien

```
hilo1 = threading.Thread(target=dormir,kwargs={"segundos": 15})
```

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente porque estás intentando algo como esto:

```
hilo1 = threading.Thread(target=dormir(5))
hilo2 = threading.Thread(target=soñar(4))
```

Lo que hay que pasarle a `target` es una función. En este caso estarías *invocando la función* (y pasando en `target` el valor retornado).

Cuando quieras pasar argumentos a la función, debes pasárselos a `Thread()` en su parámetro `args` (o `kwargs` para argumentos con nombre), ya que es `Thread()` quien al final hará la invocación de esa función (en otro hilo).

Es decir:

```
hilo1 = threading.Thread(target=dormir, args=(5,))
hilo2 = threading.Thread(target=soñar, args=(4,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra opcion es heredar la clase [Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#module-threading).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
import threading
class Holgazan(threading.Thread):
    actividad = ""

    def __init__(self, actividad):
        self.actividad = actividad
        super(App, self).__init__()
    def dormir():
        print("Me duermo")
        time.sleep(10)

        print("Me despierto")
    def soñar():
        for i in range(9):
            time.sleep(1)
            print(i," Zzzzzzzz")
    def run(self):
        print("tipo de holgazan %s".format(self.actividad))
        if (self.actividad == "dormir"):
            self.dormir()
        else:
            self.soñar()
```

y para instanciar la clase la usamos de la siguiente forma:

```
jackNavaRow = Holgazan("")
abulafia    = Holgazan("dormir")
jackNavaRow.start() 
abulafia.start()
```